# Auto-refresh on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Is there a way to set an auto-refresh on IE8? I want to refresh Superuser's page on a specific interval. Like each minutes...

Comment: For the record the Super User home page is cached and refreshed every 1 minute already. To prevent being blocked rather use the RSS feed to keep up to date or alternatively refresh the page every 2 - 3 minutes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yrefresher](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/yrefresher.html) should do the trick

> This Internet Explorer addon
>   automatically refreshes websites for
>   you. You can set it to refresh your
>   pages at custom intervals or any
>   predefined ones. Each browser window
>   has its own refresh control available
>   from the IE toolbar. handy for
>   monitoring auctions, stocks or any
>   other pages that change frequently.

[image]

Comment: I will upvote in 22 hours...

Comment: OT: snapfiles (and others) don't like their screen shots hotlinked, please use another image or use an image hosting service to upload the image there, most support upload via URL, if you're using FF, there are several addons supporting various image hosting services.

Comment: @Molly thanks - I generally upload to Imageshack using an app coded by me, but certain times I can't use the app (eg: when I'm in office, both imagesharing sites are blocked) - I just put in the image from the original source.