# What is the easiest way to make your browser refresh a page every say, 5 seconds?

Tags: browser

Is there a browser that supports refreshing a page every say, 5 seconds? Is there an add-on?

If not, is there a more simple way than writing a full (C# or Java) program in order to do that?

**Added:** Opera is horrible! I set Stack Overflow to refresh every 5 seconds, but when I click on a post, it refreshes it every 5 secs too! I just wanted the main page to refresh every 5 seconds.

**Another "Added":** apparently it refreshes the current tab, so as long as I open the post in a new tab, it works great.

Comment: Whatever solution you select, it might be good to see *what* is being refreshed. Like Drostie's Greasemonkey option will NOT make your browser request cached things again (which is GOOD), while other solutions might make your browser request ALL anew. This is like the difference between typing a URL (or a bookmark, or hitting Ctrl-L followed by Return) compared to hitting refresh. The latter makes most browsers even [ask the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435228/does-google-analytics-have-peformance-overhead/1184478#1184478) if cached things need updating. That slows down things.

Comment: Also, some solutions might render the refreshed page in a nicer way than other solutions -- like I would hate to *see* a page being fully rendered all over again. Also, I assume most (if not all) answers imply that the browser will scroll back to the top of the page? (Curious about which answer turns out to work best for you!)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/110233/auto-refresh-on-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/) supports this feature out of the box. Go to the webpage, right click and select Reload Every.

See the following screenshot for illustration:

[image: reload every in action]

You might also be interested in the [Check4Change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3028/) extension for Firefox.

Comment: Not sure if it is available in current version

Comment: not available now

Answer (score 13):

Or for Firefox, use the following one-liner as a [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/748) script:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = window.location.href; }, 5000);
```

Comment: `window.location.reload(false)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location is at the least more readable, if not faster. Also, if you're using a Greasemonkey script, you can always `GM_registerMenuCommand` instead of always refreshing on that page.

Comment: @Hello71, without trying in Greasemonkey but when using Safari on a Mac: just pasting the following in the location bar, `javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href` renders MUCH nicer than `javascript:window.location.reload(false)` (which completely clears the window first). Given the documentation, I don't understand why though...

Comment: @Arjan: With a little testing, I found out that setting `window.location.href` to itself only reloads if the page does not have a hash at the end of it (`#12345`).

Comment: @Hello71, again just using the location bar, not Greasemonkey: `javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href` works fine for me (testing with Stack Overflow, without anything such as Web Inspector open, and taking the cache of the site itself into account as well). But: your findings might make sense, as the hash is not included in `location.href`, as it's really client side only.

Comment: @Arjan: Firefox doesn't even send a request, according to Firebug and my poor skills with Wireshark.

Comment: @Hello, having Firebug open changes a lot (often sends *more* requests then). But I'm sure things can be different in different browsers.

Comment: @Hello, I was wrong about `javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href` working fine when the original URL has a hash. That indeed does not always work. And when it doesn't, the `javascript` just sits in the location bar forever...

Answer (score 4):

Opera has a *Reload Every* option built into it.

If you use Firefox you can download the [ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) addon.

Answer (score 3):

you can do with /bin/bash and links (or any other command like curl or wget)

```
while true;                                                                                                                                                 
do
    links http://127.0.0.1:3000 -dump > /dev/null 
    sleep 2
done
```

if you need to see the html use -source instead of -dump ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) addon! It is available for **IE, Firefox and Chrome**.

iMacros is a great (and open source) web browser macro recorder addon, and [refreshing a website](http://wiki.imacros.net/REFRESH) is dead simple with it. Use this macro:

```
  VERSION BUILD=7000928 RECORDER=FX
  REFRESH
  WAIT SECONDS=5
```

and start it with the [LOOP button](http://wiki.imacros.net/Automation#Play_.28Loop.29_Button).

If you want to make sure that the page is *really* completely reloaded (not from cache) use the [CLEAR](http://wiki.imacros.net/CLEAR) command and reload the complete website via [URL](http://wiki.imacros.net/URL) GOTO command:

```
  VERSION BUILD=7000928 RECORDER=FX
  CLEAR
  URL GOTO=http://superuser.com/
  WAIT SECONDS=5
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Looks interesting.. I should consider if it's worth the effort though, as there are "out of the box" solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the [Auto Refresh add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auto-refresh) and it works great.

Comment: Please refer to [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) when answering questions with a product recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

To enable auto refresh in Chrome, download and install the Auto Refresh Plus extension from the Web Store.

To integrate the feature in Firefox, download and install Auto Refresh add-on, the one that [Nuno](https://superuser.com/users/189866/nuno) recommended, and restart your browser. Then open the web page you want to refresh and select the time period of auto refresh from the right-click menu under the Auto refresh option.

Just like [Om Nom Nom](https://superuser.com/users/24604/om-nom-nom) said, auto reload option is available in Opera by default and thus one does not need an extension.

Here is the link to the original articol with screenshots and more information:

http://www.guidingtech.com/12491/auto-refresh-pages-chrome-firefox-opera/

Comment: Can you summarize the information at the link in your answer in case the page disappears.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for those who cannot install any external extensions...

```javascript
var w = window.open(window.location.href);
setInterval(function(){w.window.location.reload()},10000)
```

this will duplicate a tab and reload it every 10 second (10000 milisecond), change it as required

put above code in a book marklet converter like https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/

here is the bookmarklet for it, add this to bookmark panel

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20w%20%3D%20window.open(window.location.href)%3BsetInterval(function()%7Bw.window.location.reload()%7D%2C10000)%7D)()
```

or you can click on [this](https://javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20w%20%3D%20window.open(window.location.href)%3BsetInterval(function()%7Bw.window.location.reload()%7D%2C10000)%7D)()) to try it out... (or drag to bookmarklet panel)

https://gist.github.com/Vaisakhkm2625/ca8b9acd5517eb768b14f05c7a98bcfe