# How can I make the browser automatically do some operations (such as refresh the webpage every a few minutes)?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, internet, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to make your browser refresh a page every say, 5 seconds?](https://superuser.com/questions/200088/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-make-your-browser-refresh-a-page-every-say-5-seconds)
>   [How can I run a web page in task scheduler every day?](https://superuser.com/questions/329099/how-can-i-run-a-web-page-in-task-scheduler-every-day)

Are there some ways to make the browser automatically do some operations (such as refresh the webpage every a few minutes) to avoid being idle?

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10 and browsers are Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a web browser, when you can just keep a terminal window open running a ping?

Comment: If you look at the earlier version of the question, M. West, you'll see that the questioner is trying to earn the equivalent of the "Enthusiast" badge on "some forums".  As such, this question is a duplicate of ["How can I run a web page in task scheduler every day?"](http://superuser.com/questions/329099/) where [the questioner is trying to cheat the StackExchange system](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3298/).

Answer (score 2):

There are addons for both Firefox and Chrome that does this.
Here are two examples, Firefox:[ReloadEvery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) Crome:[Page Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmooaemjmediafeacjplpbpenjnpcneg)

But if you just want to keep a connection alive you could use this bash oneliner

```
while true; do wget -qO- http://www.google.com > /dev/null; sleep 300; done
```

or

```
while true; do curl -s http://www.google.com > /dev/null; sleep 300; done
```

it will download www.google.com every 300 seconds and throw away the result.

Comment: Thanks! Are the last two methods by wget and by curl  able to make me login and keep me stay as such?